# Background process c

Tags: c, background, operating-system

I am making a shell and I am confused as to what to do if a command is to be put in the background.
I have parsed my commands, and fork works for commands that are in the foreground. I have it so it can be determined if a command is to be put in the background. I'm not really sure what to do in the first else if of my code. Any pointers on how to approach background commands would be appreciated.

```
pid_t childpid;
int status; 
childpid = fork();
if (childpid >= 0)                            // fork succeeded 
{
    if (childpid == 0 && background == 0)     // fork() returns 0 to the child
    {
        if (execv(path, strs) < 0)
        {
            perror("Error on execv.");
        }
        exit(0);                              // child exits  
    }
    else if (childpid == 0 && background ==1)
    {
        // What goes here?              
    }
    else                                      // fork() returns new pid to the parent 
    {
        wait(&status);  
    }
}
else                                          // fork returns -1 on failure
{
    perror("fork");                           // display error message 
    exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: As Joachim said, it is the parent code that is different, not the child code.  As a point of detail, you probably want the child to die with a non-zero exit code (1, or perhaps 126 or 127 if you want to be POSIX compliant) when it fails to `execve()`.  Also, you've got a 'bushy' decision tree.  Try to rewrite the code to avoid making decisions immediately after making decisions: `if (childpid < 0) ...error... else if (childpid == 0) ...execve... else if (background == 0) ...wait loop... else ...process run in background...`. Note `wait loop`; you might have prior background processes complete.

Answer (score 1):

The *child* doesn't care if it's run in the background or not, so just call `exec` as usual. It's in the *parent* process you have to behave differently.

First of all you can no longer use `wait` as that will block the parent process. Instead you can use [`waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) with a negative pid and the `WNOHANG` flag to check for terminated child processes without blocking.

Another common solution that doesn't involve calling `waitpid` at regular intervals is to use the `SIGCHLD` signal, which will be raised when a child process is stopped or terminated.